# stretchable columns from code in Android

Tags: java, c#, android

I'm insert a table from code.
Here is my code from XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TableLayoutInsert"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/TableLayoutShow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*"></TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is my code form MainActivity:

```
 t1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayoutShow);
    t1.setColumnStretchable(1, true);
    t1.setColumnStretchable(2, true);
    ViewAll();
```

And this is ViewAll code:

```
Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
    while(res.moveToNext())
    {
        tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        src1 = new TextView(this);
        src1.setText(res.getString(0));
        src1.setTextSize(15);
        src1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        src1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        src1.setWidth(50);
        tr.addView(src1);

        src2 = new TextView(this);

        src2.setText(res.getString(1));

        src2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        src2.setTextSize(15);
        src2.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        tr.addView(src2);
        src2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        src3 = new TextView(this);

        src3.setText(res.getString(2));
        src3.setTextSize(15);
        src3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        src3.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        tr.addView(src3);

        t1.addView(tr);
    }
```

Please help me, it shown but, column 2 and column 3 is wrap content, not stretchable. Thank you.